# How to create an UEFI bootable USB stick from an ISO

Tags: usb, boot, uefi

I have an ISO image of my backup solution's recovery cd. When I burn the image to a CD-ROM, I can boot from it in UEFI or normal mode without problems.

Unfortunately, this is no solution for my laptop, as it does not have an optical drive. Thus,  I tried to create a bootable USB stick that can also boot in UEFI mode, but so far I have not been successful (note that the laptop has UEFI and boots Windows 7 in UEFI mode).

So my question is, if anyone knows how I can get said ISO on my USB stick so that it boots as if I would use a CD-ROM?

Comment: What process are you using to create the bootable USB stick.

Comment: I have searched for some tools to create bootable USB sticks (Unetbootin, Rufus, make_me_bootable among others). But either they weren't able to create a bootable USB stick at all, or it was only bootable in normal and not UEFI mode.

Comment: Related / dup: http://superuser.com/questions/531793/installing-windows-8-in-uefi-mode-not-booting

Comment: The guys at eightforums has a good step by step ---> [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html)

Comment: Perhaps it would be simplier to change the bios from uefi to Compatibility Support Mode (CSM)

Answer (score 4):

Please clarify: can you boot that CD in *both* BIOS and UEFI modes? E.g. does it have two boot records in boot menu or a mode switch knob?

Preparing a UEFI-bootable USB flash drive is actually way simpler compared to an ISO, at least has been so in my experiments: a FAT partition with `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` which knows what to do next compared to specially crafted El Torito boot floppy image with the same crap.

Maybe you'll need to extract that `efiboot` image, `mount -o loop` it and extract the contents into `EFI/BOOT` directory.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply format the flash drive as FAT32 and copy the contents of the ISO to it.

I believe that you don't need any further steps.

Comment: unfortunately not; even if I make the partition active

Comment: Windows won't let files which are > 4 GB be copied over to a FAT32 drive, even when you have plenty of free space. The drive may need to be reformatted as exFat.

Answer (score 2):

[Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie)
supports BIOS and UEFI systems.

You need to set the filesystem as FAT32. By default Rufus uses NTFS and that's not readable by UEFI.

Comment: This doesn't work. It says "0 devices found". See http://i.stack.imgur.com/5VVwV.png

Comment: Rufus may not give a FAT32 option if the downloaded ISO is > 4 GB. I tried using Rufus & discovered that the ISO which it downloads was 5 GB. It was above the 4 GB FAT32 OS threshold. I had to reformat a 32 GB FAT32 USB stick as exFat. Then I could copy the 5 GB ISO onto it. If Rufus only shows NTFS, check the file size to see if it's > 4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

I just put the full [Eightforums guide](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-in-windows.15458/#step9) here, but all the credits go there. Many guys here (SLaks and Michael Shigorin) proposed the idea, but neither offered the idea exact implementation steps as 8forums guys did.

Here they are:

1. Insert USB-stick and open elevated command propmpt
2. ```
   diskpart
   list disk
   ```

   Observe the list and pick the number your USB-stick was assigned, then select it via that number

   ```
   select disk #
   ```
3. Create single FAT32 partition on it

   ```
   detail disk
   clean
   create partition primary
   format fs=fat32 quick
   active
   assign
   list volume
   exit
   ```
4. Final step. Copy the contents of the boot ISO to the stick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most UEFI systems will be able to boot only x64 boot media in UEFI mode as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1265484/possible-to-install-windows-8-1-10-32-bit-while-in-uefi-mode)
2. With customized ISOs, it will always be experimental and may support one or the other.
3. Normally, UEFI boot needs a FAT32 format drive or such partition on the boot drive. But FAT32 can only support files that are less than or equal to 4GB. So, the Isos, which are having files ( extracted ) larger than 4GB, has to be applied to the boot media with some tricks.
4. **SLaks** way will be possible only as long as the biggest file (normally `install.wim`) is lesser or equal to 4GB because it uses single FAT32 partition on the boot drive.
5. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) uses a single FAT32 partition when the biggest file is under or equal to 4GB **otherwise**, you will only have NTFS as an option with UEFI + GPT. That way, you will need to disable **Secure Boot** in the UEFI firmware to boot into the media. Once Installation or Repair is complete, you can again turn Secure Boot On, **but** Secure Boot disabling/enabling is not very straight forward in all UEFI firmware such as some [Asus Motherboards](https://www.technorms.com/45538/disable-enable-secure-boot-asus-motherboard-uefi-bios-utility)

**Methods:** *(assumes the largest file is less than 4 GB)*

(A) **SLaks way**

1. Download the required ISO : [Win 8/8.1/10](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php) / [Win 7](https://the-eye.eu/public/MSDN/Windows%207/)
2. Extract the ISO to a folder with a good archiver, such as[7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) / [WinRAR](https://www.win-rar.com/predownload.html?&L=0)
3. Insert the pen drive & format it as FAT32
4. Copy all the files from the extracted ISO folder to the root of the pen drive
5. The drive is ready to boot from *(will be bootable in both UEFI & MBR)*

(While working with ISOs with `.wim` & `.swm` files, this way, they always booted in both UEFI & MBR)

(B) **Rufus Way**

1. Insert the pen drive
2. Launch Rufus & follow the below image and instructions:

[image: Rufus: Biggest file 4GB]

```
- *Drive will be formatted, so back up any important data on it*
```

3. Select the pen drive in the **Device** menu
4. Click **SELECT**, browse to the Win 7/8/8.1/10 iso and double click it

   - *It will show under **Boot selection** (marked as **blue** in the
     Image)*
5. Choose **Partition scheme** as ***GPT*** & **Target system** as ***UEFI***
6. Press **START**
7. Once it shows **READY**, it's done, and you can close Rufus

**Methods:** *(assume largest file > 4GB)*

Do you have a file(s) larger than 4GB?

When the largest file(s) is / are greater than 4GB,

**SLaks** way will prompt you with something like 'the file size is not suitable for ...'

**Rufus** will give you no option of FAT32 against UEFI + GPT, leaving only NTFS to go with!

***(Obviously, these methods will also work when the largest file(s) is / are smaller or equal to 4GB!)***

**The ways:**

(A) **Rufus**: Go with UEFI + GPT + NTFS & Disable **Secure Boot** to boot into the media!

(B) Change & Replace the `.wim` file to `.esd` file & use the **SLaks** way.

There are many ways to do that like [DISM++](https://www.chuyu.me/en/index.html)

(But I won't suggest that because that process takes up a lot of resources. If your system is not powerful enough, It will substantially paralyze your system!)

(C) Split & replace `.wim` file to multiple `.swm` files which should be smaller than 4GB individually!

I found that only one file was over 4GB in the ISO which was `install.wim`. All other files & `boot.wim` was well under 4GB. So, we have to split & replace `install.wim`

We will use : [wimlib-imagex](https://wimlib.net/)

The general command is :

```
wimlib-imagex split --check windows.wim windows.swm 100
```

We want to split `install.wim` in **1200MB** `install.swm` chunks.
So, the general command for us :

```
wimlib-imagex split --check install.wim install.swm 1200
```

**But..**
we will need to tell path(s) for everything wherever needed.

For a practical eg.:

1. Extract the **windows iso** to a folder with an archiver: **7zip** / **WinRAR**
2. Make 3 folders in the `c:` root i.e.: `c:\New 1` , `c:\New 2` & `c:\New 3`
3. Extract the downloaded **wimlib zip file** to the root of the **New 1** folder.
4. In the **extracted iso** folder, navigate to **Sources** folder. Drag & drop `.install.wim` to **New 2** folder.
5. Open a command prompt.
6. Copy, Paste & Run this command as it is **(with quotes!)**:

```
"c:\New 1\wimlib-imagex" split --check "c:\New 2\install.wim" "c:\New 3\install.swm" 1200
```

7. Wait for the things to finish.
8. **Exit** command prompt.
9. Your `install.swm` files are ready in `c:\New 3`
10. Navigate to the extracted iso folder & Replace `install.wim` with `install.swm` files.
11. Format the pen drive with **FAT32**.
12. Drag & drop the Iso extracted folder ( in which we have replaced **install.wim** with **install.swm** file**s** ), to the pen drive & let it finish.

It's done!

***(This way** the pen drive will be bootable into both **UEFI** & **MBR)***

Comment: 1. When Rufus uses NTFS with UEFI + GPT, It still makes a small FAT32 partition ( along with an NTFS Partition! ) on the boot drive but one will need to disable Secure Boot in order to boot in that media as said above. 2. I appreciate, thank & request people here @SuperUser to keep on helping us with their fine tunings. Thanks & Regards. ...

Comment: Please use the correct markdown formatting for number and unnumbered lists, as well as for monospaced code.  When you edit your post, at the far right of the formatting bar there will be a question mark icon... please click it to get help with how to use markdown _(you can also see how it's implemented from the first edit I performed to the top of your answer)_.In its current form _without markdown formatting_, your answer is taxing to read, as it's severely muddled.  Once markdown is applied, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: I have chosen above the chunk size of Install.swm files as 1200 MB. In case of a very big Install.wim, the chunk size can be maximized @ 4GB i.e. 4000 MB.

Comment: Please, please use the correct markdown when writing... if you don't edit this yourself, it's going to take someone with editing privileges over a half hour to fix your answer _(just as it took me over a half-hour to fix your initial lack of markdown)_ and a person with editing privs shouldn't have to do something the author should be doing on their own, especially when they were made aware of markdown beforehand.

Comment: On a separate note, why are you referencing DISM++? Has this program been vetted by any independent third party? Trusted GUIs exist for `DISM`, such as the GUI in PowerShell ISE's module browser, however DISM++ throws up enormous red flags, one of which is they're not licensed by Microsoft to use their IP.  I'm also a bit confused by the `ImageX` libraries... `ImageX` is only compatible with Windows <=7 and cannot be used for any imaging on Windows >=8 (`DISM` is used). Why is the wheel attempting to be re-invented here? _Have you confirmed if the Windows installer recognizes `.swm` files?_

Comment: _Have you confirmed if the Windows installer recognizes **.swm** files?_ Yes Sir.

Comment: I am submitting this comment to nearly every one of your answers.  We do not consider greetings, salutations, or signatures to be helpful.  So please avoid using this in your answers in the future.  Specifically with regards to this answer, even after numerous revisions, it had numerous grammatical mistakes.  Please take a moment and use the appropriate tools to avoid that issue in the future.  Contributions that have numerous grammatical mistakes often will result in a downvote.

Comment: I would like to add that Windows 7 Installation media does not cooperate with 'Install.esd' file. So, that will not be the option for windows 7, unless installation files are borrowed from windows 8 or 10 installation media. Though the untouched MSDN windows 7 sp1 32 / 64 ISOs have 'Install.wim' file less than 4GB in size, that may exceed with updates integration!