# Installing Windows 8 in UEFI mode not booting

Tags: windows-8, usb, installation, uefi

Installing Windows 8 in UEFI mode using a usb is not working for me. I followed various instructions on the web on making a UEFI bootable usb, but to no avail.

On my (ASUS) computer's booting menu, I am able to boot both the normal usb and UEFI usb, and when I boot without UEFI, I can get to the installation process without any problems, but only a blinking cursor shows up when I try the other one.

Something to note, however, is that I had no problem installing Ubuntu (12.04) using UEFI from a usb on my computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: By "USB" are you referring to a USB flash drive, a USB DVD drive, or something else?

Comment: I was refering to the flash drive.

Comment: How did you create the USB-based setup? Is the drive formatted as NTFS? Format it as FAT32 instead and see if it works.

Comment: I did format in FAT32 creating the USB setup. Tried with Windows USB/DVD Tool, WinToFlash software, and the command line using DISKPART. It didn't work. I even tried using a different USB and on different USB ports, with no success. Maybe the boot setting is the problem...

Comment: I edited the question to make it more general, I think it doesn't apply just to Windows 8 / Windows.

Comment: Related / dup: http://superuser.com/questions/497672/how-to-create-an-uefi-bootable-usb-stick-from-an-iso