# Can't start windows installer from a USB drive on an UEFI-GPT-Windows scenario

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bsod, uefi

I had my laptop happily running Windows 8.1 on a GPT formatted disk booting in UEFI mode. I installed some driver updates (I suspect either the display driver or IRST might be causing the issue). After which I am not able to boot into windows at all. I shows the NEW BSOD ("Something went wrong .. ") and restarts and the loop continues. I can't get to Safe mode or any other recovery mode. Did the midway restarts, pressing down shift key trick etc etc. Nothing could get me to the recovery options menu.

So, I thought I can try to get to it from a bootable windows USB. I tried the media creation too (in another PC) and Rufus (with different options like, GPT for UEFI, MBR for UEFI-CSM etc). Nothing works. I am not able to boot from the USB drive at all. I disabled secure boot and tried with CSM ON. NO luck. Any suggestions ?

My ultrabook is HP Envy 4-1002tx. It got an SSD in Smart response mode(through IRST) and  switchable graphics (Intel HD 4000 and Radeon HD 7600)

EDIT: I was able to UEFI boot into a live Ubuntu from USB formatted in GPT using Rufus.

Comment: Lookup the hotkey to press during boot to get to the BIOS, then Windows should take over and bring you to the recovery screen, where you can find the _boot from another device_ menu under the _advanced_ button. If that doesn't work, perhaps try unplugging the hard drive to see if you can at least boot from the USB. If you don't want to do that, legacy mode in the BIOS may convince the computer to boot from the USB, though that'll mess with the current UEFI installation on the hard drive - so I don't fully recommend that.

Comment: Good suggestions. 
Well I got in and out of the BIOS a number of times. nothing really changed. Also, I cant unplug the HDD of my laptop. Leagacy mode - Sure that is where I am headed if everything fails.

Comment: Go ahead and disable CSM it needs to be disabled.  You should do what this answer says to do: https://superuser.com/questions/497672/how-to-create-an-uefi-bootable-usb-stick-from-an-iso?rq=1

Comment: Almost all my attempts have been made using a Disabled CSM and Secure boot. Still no avail.